# Replace empty columns with NA's in nested lists within lists

Tags: r, list, na

I have produced 10 nested lists within lists using two functions (below) - produced from dummy data called `normalised_scores`. Each nested list contains two empty columns called `Predicted` and `Actual` (code below). I would like to replace these empty columns with NA's. I tried to achieve this  with a function (`Shuffle100`) but got `error messages (below)`. After looking online for a long time, I cannot find an efficient method apart from using long-winded code (below). If anyone can help, then thank you.

## Dummy data

```
   Family=rep(c("G8", "V4"), each=40)
   x <- matrix(rnorm(960), ncol=12)
   normalised_scores <- cbind(Family, x)
   colnames(my_data)<-c("Family",
                        "Swimming", 
                        "Not.Swimming",
                        "Running", 
                        "Not.Running",
                        "Fighting",
                        "Not.Fighting",
                        "Resting",
                        "Not.Resting",
                        "Hunting",
                        "Not.Hunting",
                        "Grooming",
                        "Not.Grooming")
```

I wrote this function below to produce these 10 nested lists from classification tree models using `rpart` and `caret` packages. I tried to produce two columns (`Predicted` and `Actual`) filled with `NA's`using this function but without success.

```
 library(caret)
 library(e1071)
 library(rpart)

shuffle100 <-lapply(seq(10), function(n){ #Select the production of 10 dataframes
subset <- normalised_scores[sample(nrow(normalised_scores), 80),] #Shuffle  rows
subset_idx <- sample(1:nrow(subset), replace = FALSE)
subset <- subset[subset_idx, ] #training subset
subset1<-subset[-subset_idx, ] #test subset
subset_resampled_idx <- createDataPartition(subset_idx, times = 1, p = 0.7, list = FALSE) #70 % training set    
subset_resampled <- subset[subset_resampled_idx, ]
ct_mod<-rpart(Family~., data=subset_resampled, method="class",  control=rpart.control(cp=0.005)) #10 ct
ct_pred<-predict(ct_mod, newdata=subset[, 2:13]) 
ct_dataframe=as.data.frame(ct_pred) #create new data frame
ct_dataframe$Predicted=NA
ct_dataframe$Actual=NA
})
```

Produce two empty columns called Predicted and Actual

```
my_list <- lapply(shuffle100, function(df){#Create two new columns Predicted and Actual
           if (nrow(df) > 0)
           cbind(df, Predicted = c(""), Actual = c(""))
           else
           cbind(df, Predicted = character(), Actual = c(""))
})
```

Error messages from the function `Shuffle100` and much of the same (lists 1-10):

```
               [[1]]
                [1] NA

               [[2]]
                [1] NA

               [[3]]
                [1] NA
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
          #Insert NA's

          my_list[[1]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[1]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[2]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[2]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[3]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[3]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[4]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[4]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[5]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[5]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[6]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[6]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[7]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[7]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[8]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[8]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[9]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[9]]$Actual<-NA

          my_list[[10]]$Predicted<-NA
          my_list[[10]]$Actual<-NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `transform`

```
lapply(my_list, transform, Predicted=NA, Actual=NA)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr's mutate function, try

```
    library(dplyr)
    lapply(my_list, function(x) mutate(x, Predicted = NA, Actual = NA)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to do this all day. Have a great week.

Comment: What is `dplyr` used here for? Can't you use `transform` from base R instead `mutate`?

Comment: sure! I just work with dplyr so much that I forget about the base functions sometimes..